# Svn authorizing over sasl+ldap failing after Ubuntu update 10.04 -> 12.04

Tags: svn, ldap, ubuntu-12.04, sasl

I have working svnserve solution on Ubuntu 10.04 for authorizing svn users over SASL to Active directory (LDAP, not LDAPDB). Config files are at the bottom.

After upgrading server to 12.04 release, this does not work anymore.
I can authorize user over SASL to LDAP with

```
 testsaslauthd -u ldap_username -p his_password
 => 0: OK "Success."
```

But when i try to "svn update" on folder at the same server, it ask me three times for credentials and end with

```
 svn: Authentication error from server: SASL(-4): no mechanism available:
```

I do not know how to track communication between svn and sasl.

### Circumstances:

- Ubuntu 10.04 + subversion 1.6.6 (with Cirrus SASL  support) => working
- Ubuntu 12.04 + subversion 1.6.17 (with Cirrus SASL  support) => not working (with same configuration)

file  /usr/lib/sasl2/svn.conf

```
 pwcheck_method: saslauthd
 auxprop_plugin: ldap
 mech_list: PLAIN
```

file  /usr/lib/sasl2/subversion.conf -> symlink to /usr/lib/sasl2/svn.conf

file  /opt/svn/repos/conf/svnserve.conf

```
 [general]
 anon-access = none
 auth-access = write
 #password-db = passwd
 authz-db = authz
 realm = smartsvn

 [sasl]
 use-sasl = true
 min-encryption = 0
 max-encryption = 256
```

Any idea, how to fixit or trace the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problems like above only on debian squeeze after a dist-upgrade. After hours of config, restart and reinstalling madness I gave following "svn.conf" a try:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
#auxprop_plugin: ldap
mech_list: plain login cram-md5 digest-md5
```

IMO, "mech_list: plain" should be enough. the other mechs are overlefts from previous tryouts.

Here is my  /etc/saslauthd.conf

```
ldap_servers: ldap://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ldap_use_sasl:no
ldap_search_base: DC=domain,DC=tdl
ldap_bind_dn: xxxx@domain.tdl
ldap_bind_pw: magic_word:)
ldap_mech: PLAIN
ldap_auth_method: bind
ldap_filter: (sAMAccountName=%U)
log_level: 7
```

And here my /etc/default/saslauthd

```
START=yes
DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon"
NAME="saslauthd"
MECHANISMS="ldap"
MECH_OPTIONS=""
THREADS=5
```

**Update Dez 14:**

Today I had the same issue again after an svnserve upgrade (r1615264):

I had to add the following to the svn.conf:

```
ldapdb_uri: ldap://myldadphost.tld
```

Don´t ask me why, I just tried it, because three or four years ago the param was already  (with other ldap params) in the svn.conf...

Comment: Yes, this finally helps! After restart of  `saslauthd` and  `svnserve`. Mazbe the key is case in  `mech_list: plain login` instead  `mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN`

Answer (score 2):

(1) In /etc/sasl2/svn.conf you can set a log level for saslauthd like:

```
log_level: 7
```

In sasl.h I found:

```
#define SASL_LOG_NONE  0    /* don't log anything */
#define SASL_LOG_ERR   1    /* log unusual errors (default) */
#define SASL_LOG_FAIL  2    /* log all authentication failures */
#define SASL_LOG_WARN  3    /* log non-fatal warnings */
#define SASL_LOG_NOTE  4    /* more verbose than LOG_WARN */
#define SASL_LOG_DEBUG 5    /* more verbose than LOG_NOTE */
#define SASL_LOG_TRACE 6    /* traces of internal protocols */
#define SASL_LOG_PASS  7    /* traces of internal protocols, including passwords */
```

It seems it logs to /var/log/auth.log.

I have almost the same problem (migrating from Ubuntu 11.04 to 12.04) and get in auth.log:

```
svnserve: could not find auxprop plugin, was searching for 'ldap'
```

Interestingly, the log says "svnserve" and not saslauthd. Which lead me to ...

(2) You could try

```
ldd /usr/bin/svnserve
```

For me, the working server (Ubuntu 11.04) shows:

```
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
```

but the failing server (12.04) does not.

Comment: I filed a question with canonical's ubuntu launchpad:https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subversion/+question/225260

Comment: Became a bug now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subversion/+bug/1160896

Comment: I see, thanks. After raising log level I have similiar error to yours:

Comment: I see, thanks. After raising log level I have similiar error to yours:  `svnserve: could not find auxprop plugin, was searching for 'ldapdb'` (Marcin configuration). I tried also change configuration in /usr/lib/sasl2/svn.conf to `auxprop_plugin: ldap` but error is just switch to `svnserve: could not find auxprop plugin, was searching for 'ldap'`.

Comment: After not getting an answer in the svn users mailing list, I now resort to using Apache and https:// instead of svn://. LDAP works there and it is much more secure anyway. I tried to avoid this because http used to take 60% longer for a checkout (with my use case here), but newer tests show that this is less of an issue with subversion 1.8 on the server side and on the client side together with serf (instead of neon).

Answer (score 1):

Try changeing configuration to your /usr/lib/sasl2/svn.conf config file (SVN sasl configuration):

```
auxprop_plugin: ldapdb
mech_list: PLAIN
ldapdb_mech: PLAIN
saslauthd_path: /var/run/saslauthd/mux
ldapdb_uri: <address of your ldap server (ldap://hostname)>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but didnot work. I updated svn.conf, restart svnserve and saslauthd, but error is the same.